# Extract element's content from a file, and append it on input file, based on a key match, with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

File a.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TABLE NAME="pivot.cs">
   <DATA RECORDS="2">
      <RECORD ID="1">
         <INTERNALID>5510</INTERNALID>
         <SOMED>1</SOMED>
         <PEMED>1</PEMED>
         <CODAL>PLACEHOLD</CODAL>
      </RECORD>
      <RECORD ID="2">
         <INTERNALID>5511</INTERNALID>
         <SOMED>1</SOMED>
         <PEMED>1</PEMED>
         <CODAL>PLACEHOLD</CODAL>
      </RECORD>
      <RECORD ID="3">
      <INTERNALID>5537</INTERNALID>
      <SOMED>2</SOMED>
      <PEMED>1</PEMED>
      <CODAL>PLACEHOLD</CODAL>
      </RECORD>
   </DATA>
</TABLE>
```

file b.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TABLE NAME="ALT.CS">
   <DATA RECORDS="20">
      <RECORD ID="53">
         <RECNO>5510</RECNO>
         <TOBEEXTRACTED>TIM</TOBEEXTRACTED>
      </RECORD>
      <RECORD ID="53">
         <RECNO>5510</RECNO>
         <TOBEEXTRACTED>KLM</TOBEEXTRACTED>
      </RECORD>
      <RECORD ID="54">
         <RECNO>5510</RECNO>
         <TOBEEXTRACTED>KAB</TOBEEXTRACTED>
      </RECORD>
      <RECORD ID="55">
         <RECNO>5511</RECNO>
         <TOBEEXTRACTED>BUS WEE</TOBEEXTRACTED>
      </RECORD>
         <RECORD ID="5511">
            <RECNO>5537</RECNO>
            <TOBEEXTRACTED>FBV</TOBEEXTRACTED>
         </RECORD>
      </RECORD>
   </DATA>
</TABLE>
```

i need to join info, from file b.xml, into file a. xml where INTERNALID = RECNO so as to keep current data in element CODAL, 
but append to it the TOBEEXTRACTED element's content.
The output file should be, the file a.xml, but with the TOBEEXTRACTED element text appended into [], along with a letter, 
indicating the SOMEID number: 
1 -> A, 2 -> B, 3 -> C, etc...

so the output will become:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TABLE NAME="pivot.cs">
   <DATA RECORDS="2">
      <RECORD ID="1">
         <INTERNALID>5599</INTERNALID>
         <SOMED>1</SOMED>
         <PEMED>1</PEMED>
         <CODAL>PLACEHOLD</CODAL>
      </RECORD>
      <RECORD ID="2">
         <INTERNALID>5511</INTERNALID>
         <SOMED>1</SOMED>
         <PEMED>1</PEMED>
         <CODAL>PLACEHOLD [BUS WEE A]</CODAL>
      </RECORD>
      <RECORD ID="3">
      <INTERNALID>5537</INTERNALID>
      <SOMED>2</SOMED>
      <PEMED>1</PEMED>
      <CODAL>PLACEHOLD [FBV B]</CODAL>
      </RECORD>
   </DATA>
</TABLE>
```

Comment: Isn't there a `RECORD` wrapper missing around some data, both in the input sample as in the result sample? Or where does `<INTERNALID>5537</INTERNALID>` belong to?

Comment: And why do you say that `<INTERNALID>5510</INTERNALID>` is not matched? file A has `<INTERNALID>5510</INTERNALID>` and file b has ` <RECNO>5510</RECNO>`.

Comment: My xml is huge, many more elements in each record wrapper, so by mistake i removed also the record wrapper...you are correct, just edited my question, thank you

Comment: Your example still doesn't make sense. And fileB.xml is not well-formed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your examples do not add up. Assuming you're processing the following input:

**XML**

```
<TABLE NAME="pivot.cs">
  <DATA RECORDS="3">
    <RECORD ID="1">
      <INTERNALID>5550</INTERNALID>
      <SOMEID>1</SOMEID>
      <CODAL>ZERO</CODAL>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD ID="2">
      <INTERNALID>5556</INTERNALID>
      <SOMEID>2</SOMEID>
      <CODAL>SIX</CODAL>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD ID="3">
      <INTERNALID>5557</INTERNALID>
      <SOMEID>3</SOMEID>
      <CODAL>SEVEN</CODAL>
    </RECORD>
  </DATA>
</TABLE>
```

and passing the path to another XML file:

**b.xml**

```
<TABLE NAME="ALT.CS">
  <DATA RECORDS="5">
    <RECORD ID="15">
      <RECNO>5555</RECNO>
      <TOBEEXTRACTED>ECHO</TOBEEXTRACTED>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD ID="16">
      <RECNO>5556</RECNO>
      <TOBEEXTRACTED>FOXTROT</TOBEEXTRACTED>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD ID="17">
      <RECNO>5557</RECNO>
      <TOBEEXTRACTED>GOLF</TOBEEXTRACTED>
    </RECORD>
  </DATA>
</TABLE>
```

as a parameter, you can use:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="lookup-path">path/to/b.xml</xsl:param>
<xsl:key name="lookup" match="RECORD" use="RECNO" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CODAL">
    <xsl:variable name="match" select="key('lookup', ../INTERNALID, document($lookup-path))" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="$match">
            <xsl:text> [</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$match/TOBEEXTRACTED"/>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:number value="../SOMEID" format="A" />
            <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to return:

**result**

```
<TABLE NAME="pivot.cs">
  <DATA RECORDS="3">
    <RECORD ID="1">
      <INTERNALID>5550</INTERNALID>
      <SOMEID>1</SOMEID>
      <CODAL>ZERO</CODAL>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD ID="2">
      <INTERNALID>5556</INTERNALID>
      <SOMEID>2</SOMEID>
      <CODAL>SIX [FOXTROT B]</CODAL>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD ID="3">
      <INTERNALID>5557</INTERNALID>
      <SOMEID>3</SOMEID>
      <CODAL>SEVEN [GOLF C]</CODAL>
    </RECORD>
  </DATA>
</TABLE>
```

---

**Caveat**: untested

---

### Added:

To accomplish the same thing in XSLT 1.0, you would have to do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="lookup-path">b.xml</xsl:param>
<xsl:key name="lookup" match="RECORD" use="RECNO" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CODAL">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <!-- place values from this document into variables -->
        <xsl:variable name="internal-id" select="../INTERNALID" />
        <xsl:variable name="some-id" select="../SOMEID" />
        <!-- switch context to the other document -->
        <xsl:for-each select="document($lookup-path)">
            <xsl:variable name="match" select="key('lookup', $internal-id)" />
            <xsl:if test="$match">
                <xsl:text> [</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="$match/TOBEEXTRACTED"/>
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                <xsl:number value="$some-id" format="A" />
                <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: when i gave xsltproc -o output.xml style.xsl input.xml, I got the following message:
'compilation error: file style.xsl line 2 element stylesheet
xsl:version: only 1.0 features are supported
runtime error: file style.xsl line 17 element variable
key() : expects two arguments
xmlXPathCompiledEval: 2 objects left on the stack.
runtime error: file style.xsl line 17 element variable
Failed to evaluate the expression of variable 'match'.'

Comment: Your question is tagged XSLT 2.0 and the above answer requires an XSLT 2.0 processor.  `xsltproc` supports XSLT 1.0 only (as your error message clearly states).

Comment: used xalan: xalan -xsl style.xsl -in input.xml -out output.xml
XPath error: The function 'key()' requires two arguments. (Occurred in entity 'file:///path_to/style.xsl', at line 17, column 17.)
Source tree node: CODAL. am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Xalan is an XSLT 1.0 processor too. Why did you tag your question as XSLT 2.0?

Comment: @duxok I have added an XSLT 1.0 solution to my answer. Please be more considerate next time.

Comment: used saxonb, output is identical to what you have posted. Only thing would be great if we could have in a log file, the info that the <INTERNALID>5550</INTERNALID>
was not matched

Comment: In XSLT 2.0, you can use `xsl:result-document` to create a secondary output file and populate it using a template matching orphaned nodes. Post a separate question if you cannot make it work.